# Simple client - server application via REST

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller, javafx, client-server

How can one build Java application which consists of a client and a server that communicate using REST. I've been thinking to build client using Java FX(because it looks simple) and server as a Java servlet. I am fresh with Java but I am sitting with PHP everyday so I am well awared of MVC pattern but the real question is how to get this done simply in Java? Would you recommend me some framework? The app will be really simple because it will just have only few screens. There sould also be authentication using login and password for users, but thats all! Should I look into Spring maybe? Wouldn't it be overkill?

Comment: And the reason this gets downvoted is? I am not asking you to write the hole thing up for me, just put me in some direction...

Comment: The question gets down voted because its off-topic for StackOverflow.  There are many frameworks which could be used to help you build your application.  Just for variety you could also take a look at [dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.3/docs/index.html), which is similar to, but less ambitious than, [SpringBoot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) or (the currently less mature) [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring would be a great place to start. I recently developed an application that had a client and server side using Spring, and there are plenty of tutorials out there. If it's fairly lightweight, look into Spring Boot. I recommend building your Spring application using Gradle as opposed to Maven because it's easier to resolve and use dependencies, but to each his own. IMO, Spring does a good job of handling requests and is very flexible as far as configuration. Spring is also very easy to integrate into IDEs such as Eclipse or IntelliJ.

As far as user authentication, whether it is overkill is completely up to you, but Spring has some great tutorials to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to accomplish this at this time is via Spring Boot MVC.  See https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-4-spring-mvc/

If you're doing database interactions, Spring JPA gives some very nice features, like being able to create a DAO simply by writing an interface expressing your intent for how it should behave. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Spring provides a /lot/ of services and features, but it's not overkill so long as you don't try to use them all at once.